# Testing __call() with mockery?

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-4, magic-methods, mockery

I have a pretty basic function in my class that does exactly as the comment say, it just forwards calls to the child model if they don't exist on this class.
This works perfectly from my tests.

```
/**
 * Handles calling methods on the user model directly from the provider
 * Allows e.g. Guardian::User()->findOrFail(1) without having to redeclare
 * the methods.
 *
 * @param $method
 * @param $parameters
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters){
    $user = $this->createModel();
    return call_user_func_array([$user, $method], $parameters);
}
```

However I also want to write unit tests for this, in which case the test I tried writing:

```
public function testProviderAsksModelToFind(){
    $factoryUser = Factory::attributesFor('User', ['id' => 1]);

    $p = m::mock('Webfox\Guardian\User\Guardian\Provider[createModel]',['']);

    $user = m::mock('Webfox\Guardian\User\Guardian\User[find]');

    $p->shouldReceive('createModel')->once()->andReturn($user);
    $user->shouldReceive('find')->with(1)->once()->andReturn($factoryUser);

    $this->assertSame($factoryUser, $p->find(1));
}
```

However this is spitting out the lovely error below:

> 1) EloquentUserProviderTest::testProviderAsksModelToFind
>   BadMethodCallException: Method
>   Webfox\Guardian\User\Guardian\Provider::find() does not exist on this
>   mock object

So, how do I fix this so my test passes?

Comment: ProTip: if you have static scope resolution operators all over your unit tests, you aren't actually writing *unit tests*; you're writing integration tests.

Comment: Testing magic methods is also probably a misconception for unit-tests. Units normally depend on an interface, magic methods are probably the opposite of it. Therefore you can not mock this (and/or it makes no *sense* to mock that). Instead mock and test `__call`.

Comment: @rdlowrey I only see the Factory to have static. The rest is ok,

Answer (score 0):

The funny part is that method find is called on Provider Mock class. The error claims that. Shouldn't it be:

```
$this->assertSame($factoryUser, $user->find(1));
```

?